# How to convert comma separated key value string to associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I tried searching for a quick fix to converting a comma separated key=>value string to an associative array but couldn't find any. So i had to make a quick fix myself.

ANTECEDENT

I generated an array of some form elements using Jquery, to be sent via ajax.
So I have something like:

```
var myarray = [];
var string1 = 'key1=>'+form['value1'].value; //and we have string2 and more
myarray.push(string1);
```

Then i sent "myarray" as data to the form handling script.

PROBLEM

Now i have an array to deal with in my php script. I have the following:

```
function($var,$data){
$string = $data('myarray'); //array created earlier with jquery
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
...
$string = array(0=>'key1=>value1',1=>'key2=>value2');
...
```

Meanwhle, what i need is:

```
...
$string = array('key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2');
...
```

SOLUTION

```
...
$string = $data('myarray');
$string1 = array();
foreach($string as $value){
    $split = explode('=>',$value);
    $string1[$split[0]]=$split[1];
}
...
```

Now i can access the value of each key as:

```
echo $string1['key1']; //gives value1
```

This solution can also be used in a situation where you have:

```
$string = 'key1=>value1,key2=>value2...';
$string = explode(',',$string); // same as $string = array('key1'=>'value1',...)
$string1 = array();
foreach($string as $value){
    $split = explode('=>',$value);
    $string1[$split[0]]=$split[1];
}
```

The solution is rather simpler than i expected but if you know a better way to make this kind of conversion, feel free to suggest.

Comment: You could just create a json object which you post as a string instead. Then you just need to do `$array = json_decode($_POST['your-data'], true);` in PHP and you will have an associative array.

Comment: ...also, is this your actual code? Is `$data` a function? If no, then it should throw errors, since you need to use `[]` and not `()` when accessing array elements.

Comment: json...never even crossed my mind. Thanks.

Comment: $data is from a function. I just don't want to add so many codes in my question

Comment: You mean that `$data` contains a function? When posting a question, it's good to let us know that or we won't understand what your code actually does (since we have no idea if you have a typo or not).

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the feedback. I only provided the ANTECEDENT  so everyone can have an idea of where I'm coming from. The focus is on the php part where/when/if one needs to convert `...'key=>value'...` to `$string = array('key'=>'value');`. Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can add as key value pair in javascript. Then you don't need to do any operations, can access directly in PHP.

```
var myarray = {};
myarray['key1'] = form['value1'].value;
```

In PHP :

```
$arr = $data('myarray');
echo $arr['key1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode()` to split up the string.

```
$string = 'key1=>value1,key2=>value2,key3=>value3';
$pairs = explode(',', $string);
$data = array();
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=>', $pair);
    $data[$key] = $value;
}
var_dump($data);
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/jlKsMq)